# JavaScript ONLY li text slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a **JavaScript ONLY** css slider. My previous one used jQuery but sadly my site doesn't really function when I use jQuery on it and the slider was in a iframe, and now I want to have my site without frames (they slow down the site).

My previous one looked like this with jQuery:

[image]

My code looked like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hallo</li>
  <li>Some more fading text</li>
  <li>Add as many as you like</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to have it exactly the same but only with JavaScript.

Does someone know a site like this? The sliders on Google are pretty much all with jquery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.

Markup:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

p + p { opacity: 0; }
```

JS:

```
var current = 0,
    slides = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwL1h75a/1/)

Comment: That works, nice one! Thanks for sharing. Is there any way to have it work with `li`?

Comment: My lord and saviour. Thank you, Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript Slider. Great for your use case. I hope it helps.
http://meandmax.github.io/lory/

Comment: Hi colecmc, it's a nice plugin but I'm actually looking for a simple plain Javascript script :)

Comment: It's plain js. No, jQuery. How simple are we talking here?

Comment: Correct, but I mean like a script of 10/15 lines of code.

Comment: We'll do that. Thanks for your input!